# Whenever I click on the radio button I get the error of function is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function, radio-button

I'm having a problem calling the function when the radio button is clicked; in particular I get

> `showinputfield is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick`

This is my code:

```js
function showinputfield() {
    let radio1 = document.getElementById('flexRadio1');
    let radio2 = document.getElementById('flexRadio2');
    if(radio1.checked) {
        console.log('hello1');
    } else if(radio2.checked) {
        console.log('hello2');
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check mb-3">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadio1" id="flexRadio1" value="radio1" onclick="showinputfield()">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadio1"> Radio1 </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check mb-3">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadio2" id="flexRadio2" value="radio2" onclick="showinputfield()">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadio2"> Radio2 </label>
</div>
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's defined in the same html file, this javascript code should go between

```
<script>
   function showinputfield() {
    ...
   }
</script>
```

If it's defined in another file, please check if it's included as `<script type="text/javascript" src="yourScript.js">`.

Comment: This is not the problem because I have already done what you said before

Comment: Can you provide full html? It could help to identify a problem much faster.

Comment: I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1sgu85t/) as an example